# Log level in Google Stackdriver Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, fluentd, stackdriver

Configured Google Stackdriver Logging in one of the GCE VM and everything works except Log Level . Have used the parameter log_level in the file

> /etc/google-fluentd/config.d/tomcat.conf

as per provided in http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail
but even then in Console Log Viewer cant able to view log in different levels. Is there any specif way to configure fluentd agent for Google Cloud?

Comment: You can refer to [this issue report](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/detail?id=35) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

The Google Cloud output plugin for fluentd currently uses the `severity` field to indicate the log level. See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/detail?id=35) for details. There is [an open request](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluent-plugin-google-cloud/issues/4) to make it configurable.